# How much should I cache results from System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement queries?

Tags: c#, caching, active-directory, memorycache

I am using this method to return all groups (recursively) that a user is a member of in order that I can perform some application-leve authorisation.

I am calling this quite frequently (say once every 10-20 seconds whilst the user is active) from a service process, and am able to cache the results into (say) System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.... however, it seems that the results from GetAuthorizationGroups are already being cached (i.e. the list doesn't update until I restart the service)

Does anyone know how much optimization Microsoft have already put into the framework for this sort of query? I.e. I don't want to prematurely optimise by caching unnecessarily.

```
    public static string[] GetActiveDirectoryGroups(string userName)
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain"))
        {
            using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userName))
            {
                return user != null ? 
                    user.GetAuthorizationGroups()
                        .Select(group => group.SamAccountName)
                        .ToArray()
                    : new string[] {};
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any built-in caching in System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory without explicit configuration - such as with a DirectorySearcher: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.cacheresults(v=vs.110).aspx

If you aren't doing any sort of caching, .NET won't do any caching automatically for you.  It will query Active Directory every time you run your function. It sounds like maybe you're incidentally storing the results of your Active Directory query and not seeing updates like you might expect.

Alternatively, you are making changes and then querying a domain controller which hasn't yet been replicated to.  When you restart your service your application is hitting a new domain controller where the changes were either made or have been replicated to.

All caching optimization must be done on your side, you need to decide how frequently you want to query your domain to check for membership updates.